# Resist User to go back after Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, browser, back-button

In my application after login I am going into home page. But from home page if I press browser's back button again the system sending me to the login page.

How can I resist my user doing so. If they do press the back button while he/she is logged in, the system will resend him/her to that same page, not in login.

Comment: why would you want that ? Imagine yourself being the user of a website which behaves this way - would you really like it that the website defies/ignores when you press the back-button ?

Comment: If you login into site like oracle forum, you will see, after login when you are being placed in the forum home first time, if you press the back button, it will send you to error page. I am trying to implement it, like to place the user in the home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the login page add a snippet that checks whether the user is already logged in. If he/she is; then redirect the user to login page.

```
// In the login page
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
           Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have added these code snippet, but it is not working, since if I press back button while I am in home page it does not call the Page_Load of the login page. I placed System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine in the Page_Load to see whether or not it is being called. But this statement doesn't printing anything, that means it is not being called.

Comment: Check the correct method signature. Also use AutoEventWireup = True

Comment: The AutoEventWireup was set to true before.

Answer (score 2):

At the top of your Login.aspx page, add the following line to prevent browsers from caching the login page:

```
<%@ OutputCache Location="None" NoStore="True" %>
```

Then, in Login.aspx.cs, redirect to your home page if the user is already logged in:

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        this.Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");

    base.OnPreInit(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that; the only thing you will accomplish is being annoying.

The back button is supposed to go back.